# How do I interpret Mono sampling profiler results?

Tags: c#, mono, profiling

I am analyzing the performance of a C# application running in Mono/Linux on an x86 based embedded target system. I need help in understanding the profiling results.

I want to understand where the application spends it's time and I therefore use the sampling profiler according to http://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/profile/profiler/.

When I profile the application I get very different results different times.
Sometimes I get almost 100% unmanaged hits, and sometimes almost 100% managed. Neither of the cases give me much information about the application's whereabouts (as far as I can tell, that is).

I use Mono 4.2.1:

```
$ mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.1 (Stable 4.2.1.60/804ddbc Tue May 10 14:32:13 CEST 2016)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       normal
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  x86
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            sgen
```

### Case 1, many unmanaged hits

```
$ mono --profile=log:sample=cycles/50000 myapp.exe
```

I get quite a few warnings "time went backwards", but the application carries on. This gets slightly better by increasing the cycles time (50000), but not much.

Then analysis,

```
$ mprof-report --reports=sample output.mlpd 

Statistical samples summary
    Sample type: cycles
    Unmanaged hits:    5134 (94.7%)
    Managed hits:       285 ( 5.3%)
    Unresolved hits:    106 ( 2.0%)
      Hits      % Method name
      3134  57.83 pthread_cond_wait
       683  12.60 clock_nanosleep
       341   6.29 sem_getvalue
       268   4.95 pthread_cond_timedwait
       233   4.30 __poll
       219   4.04 ioctl
       182   3.36 (wrapper native-to-managed) System.Drawing.GDIPlus/GdiPlusStreamHelper:StreamPutBytesImpl (intptr,int)
        27   0.50 __errno_location
        21   0.39 clock_gettime
        16   0.30 clock_gettime
        13   0.24 System.IO.Ports.SerialPortStream:get_bytes_in_buffer (int,int)
        13   0.24 pthread_setspecific
        11   0.20 __libc_fork
        10   0.18 modCom_Protocol.Ports.Streaming.StreamerBase:WorkerThreadReadPort ()
        10   0.18 __clock_gettime
         9   0.17 modCom_Protocol.Ports.Streaming.StreamerBase:get_WorkerThreadRunning ()
         9   0.17 (wrapper managed-to-native) object:__icall_wrapper_mono_marshal_set_last_error ()
         8   0.15 System.IO.Ports.SerialPortStream:get_BytesToRead ()
         7   0.13 System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch:GetTimestamp ()
         7   0.13 modCom_Protocol.Ports.Streaming.StreamerBase:WorkerJob ()
         6   0.11 get_bytes_in_buffer
```

### Case 2, no unmanaged hits

In another run, when I interact with the application in roughly the same way, I get the following:

```
root@periflux-64:~# mprof-report --verbose --reports=sample output.mlpd 

Statistical samples summary
    Sample type: cycles
    Unmanaged hits:       0 ( 0.0%)
    Managed hits:      5515 (100.0%)
    Unresolved hits:      0 ( 0.0%)
      Hits      % Method name
      5319  96.45 (wrapper native-to-managed) System.Drawing.GDIPlus/GdiPlusStreamHelper:StreamSizeImpl ()
       184   3.34 (wrapper native-to-managed) System.Drawing.GDIPlus/GdiPlusStreamHelper:StreamGetHeaderImpl (intptr,int)
         9   0.16 System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch:GetTimestamp ()
         2   0.04 modCom_Protocol.Tables.Crc16:ComputeChecksum (byte[])
         1   0.02 (wrapper stelemref) object:virt_stelemref_object (intptr,object)
```

Obviously, the results in the two cases differ a lot and none of them shows me much of the application's own execution.

### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong and how can I get better results?
2. What is the difference between Unmanaged and Managed hits?
3. How should I interpret the profiling results in Example 1 and 2?
4. In case 2 it appears as if my application is only doing graphics and
   nothing else. I know that is not so. Why do I get that result?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your question? I'm in the same predicament at the moment